# Request plain text file in javascript from URL?

Tags: javascript, html, blogs, browser-cache

I started a blog recently and coded it by hand. It is a static, CSS/HTML5 website. Upon sharing it with friends, I realized that when I would update it via FTP, it would be cached already by their browsers. I decided that I would keep all of my blog posts on *new* pages and then create a landing page that would somehow determine the newest post and forward users there after they clicked an *enter* button or something like that.

I was able to create a button that could forward them to a specific link, but I want to create a script that will always forward them to the newest page. So I created a file called 'getLatest.json' and uploaded it to an 'api' subfolder of my site. I then tried to use an XMLHttpRequest to load it:

```
function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            window.location = "http://latestBlogPost.com" +
            xhttp.responseText.today; 
            //Today is a parent in the object returned.
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://myWebsite.com/api/getLatest.json", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

But that didn't work. The response was a null string. I tried using jquery to no avail.

I tried uploading a file called getLatest.html which contained the url in plaintext. That didn't work either.

tl;dr: Is there some way that I can get plaintext from a URL's html content?

edit: getLatest.json and getLatest.html contain a link to the newest blog post.

Comment: Why are you posting? You need to convert the response text to a JSON object if that is what is being returned.

Comment: `xhttp.responseText` already contains the plaintext of the json file, if you use a `GET` request... You can't use `.today` on it, because `responseText` does not have a `today` property. In any case, if you want a page to not be cached, you need to set your HTTP server to send the correct header to not cache the page.

Comment: Isn't xhttp.responseText the response from the URL? Do I have do parse it with JSON?

Answer (score -1):

There are couple of ways to do this.
First your code is not working because you are using a "POST" it should be "GET", if you do that it will work.

Second easiest way is to create a java script file with variable declared and reference that file to your website

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://your javascript file"> </script>
```

This file contains your variable like this

```
var latestBlog = "http://....";
```

in your code use this variable. No more code required. but as i mentioned earlier if you change your HTTP Verb to get your code will work

Comment: This is a better idea. I'm going to use this. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I was using POST because I needed a file that wasn't cached.

Comment: If you want a file not cached append some random number as query string like http://website.com/getlatest.json?dt=86767